# Using strcat to add a whitespace onto a string literal?

Tags: c, string, csv, whitespace

Is there a way I can use `strcat` to add a trailing whitespace to a string literal? I'm reading stuff from a `csv` file and breaking it into tokens with `strtok()` then merging two different tokens with `strcat` but I want to do something so I create a whitespace between the two.

Here is an example of how my `csv` file reads:

```
"LastName, Firstname",ID
"LastName, Firstname",ID
"LastName, Firstname",ID
```

Here's my code:

```
char *firstname_token = NULL, *lastname_token = NULL, *ID_token, line[200];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
fgets(line, 200, infile);
lastname_token = strtok(line," ");
firstname_token = strtok(NULL, ",");
ID_token=strtok(NULL," ");}
```

Currently `firstname_token` reads:

```
"Lastname,
```

Currently `lastname_token` reads:

```
Firstname"
```

I want to `strcat` (or something similar) them together in the form:

```
"Lastname, Firstname"
```

but retain that whitespace in between the two but I'm not sure how since I'm having to save them originally as string literals.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "I'm having to save them originally as string literals."  ? You can not save string literals, they are set at compile-time and not modifiable. I think you are saying "string literals" when actually you mean something else

Comment: @M.M I'm still very much a noobie so maybe I have my terms wrong but for example I'm having to declare my tokens like char *firstname_token = NULL. I thought I wouldn't be allowed to change that after I give it some token value thus meaning I cant simply do something like, strcat(strcat(lastname_token, " ")firstname_token)

Comment: the result of `strtok` points into the buffer called `line`, so actually you can do that, but you should also check you are not going to exceed the space in the buffer (and also check that your strcat do not have overlapping source and destination). It would be simpler to use `snprintf` instead of `strcat` and you should probably make another buffer to work in

Comment: @M.M I tried that method of strcat(strcat()) but it breaks. I didn't know snprintf existed but that solved my problem. Thank you!!

Comment: The only string literals in the code shown are `" "` and `","`.  The data you read from the file is not a string literal, though it is formatted with quotes around the payload of the field.  Can you find and use a CSV-reading library?  Assuming not (even though it would probably be easiest), then do you need first name and last name separately, or would 'together' be OK?  If you only need them together, you can write your own `char *csv_field_end(char *field_start)` which can skip a CSV field, noting whether the first character passed is a `'"'` or not, and processing differently accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If your `.csv` file already contains the quoted field `"Lastname, Firstname"`, and that is what you need to parse from each line in the file, then there is no reason to split the lines on `commas` and then try and put the two halfs of the quoted field back together. Instead, simply locate the opening `'"'` saving a pointer to the start position within your line (say with `char *start;`) and then locate the next `'"'` in the line saving a pointer to the end position in the line (say with `char *end;`) and then simply copy from `start` to `end` into a new string (remembering to *nul-terminate* the new string)

This is made quite simple with the function `strchr` from `string.h`. Simply read each line into a buffer:

```
#define MAXC 256

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC],     /* buffer holding line */
        name[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold quoted lastname, firstname */

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {          /* read each line */
        char *start, *end;                      /* start/end pointers */
```

Then locate the first double-quote within the line, and if found, save the address to the opening-quote in `start`:

```
        if ((start = strchr (buf, '"')))                /* if start " found */
```

if found, then find the ending `'"'` beginning your search at `start + 1` and saving the address for the closing-quote in `end`, e.g.

```
            if ((end = strchr (start + 1, '"'))) {      /* if end " found */
```

finally, copy the entire quoted field to a new string (say `name`),

```
                memcpy (name, start, end - start + 1);  /* copy to name */
                name[end - start + 1] = 0;              /* nul-terminate */
```

Putting together a short example that reads your `.csv` file as input on `stdin` (you can add the code to open the filename if you like), you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 256

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC],     /* buffer holding line */
        name[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold quoted lastname, firstname */

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {          /* read each line */
        char *start, *end;                      /* start/end pointers */
        if ((start = strchr (buf, '"')))                /* if start " found */
            if ((end = strchr (start + 1, '"'))) {      /* if end " found */
                memcpy (name, start, end - start + 1);  /* copy to name */
                name[end - start + 1] = 0;              /* nul-terminate */
                printf ("%s\n", name);          /* print captured name */
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** to ensure a complete line of input fit in `buf`, you should check the final character read was `'\n'`, which is left to you, but note, there is no guarantee that the final line in the file will contain a POSIX line-ending, so the second part of the check would be that `strlen(buf) < MAXC - 1`. If either condition is satisfied, a complete line of text was read from the file)

**Example Input File**

Your input file with the addition of `1, 2, 3` following the names to distinguish the lines within the file:

```
$ cat dat/quoted.csv
"LastName1, Firstname1",ID
"LastName2, Firstname2",ID
"LastName3, Firstname3",ID
```

**Example Use/Output**

Compiling and running the code will save and output the quoted fields simply by copying the wanted characters, without having to tokenize or concatenate the pieces together.

```
$ ./bin/quotedfield < dat/quoted.csv
"LastName1, Firstname1"
"LastName2, Firstname2"
"LastName3, Firstname3"
```

There are a number of ways to do this, including simply working your way down your line buffer with a pointer and locating and counting `'"'`s, or using `strcspn/strspn`, etc.. Any way that can locate the surrounding quotes is fine. Then just copy from the opening-quote to the closing-quote into a new string, nul-terminate and you are done.

Let me know if you were attempting something other than capturing `"LastName, Firstname"` from each line in the file, or if you have further question about this approach instead of your `strtok` approach and I'm happy to help further.